# how to change dimensions of background-image?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for background-image for content section of my home page. I have found a suitable picture but it is not fitting properly behind content.

Comment: We need more information on what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve. Have you done any research on resizing background images?

Comment: `how to change dimensions of background-image?` - with an image editor?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about doing so in CSS?  Did you use

`background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;`

Please provide more info

Answer (score 0):

Try it with CSS3 property `background-size` like this

```
.element {
    background-image: url('{path}');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

See also here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

You should just use background size property:

```
background-size: 100px 50px;
```